# What is the equivalent of -llib of gcc in g++?

Tags: gcc, g++

I am compiling a cpp program with math.h using [Arm performance library](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102620/0100/Optimized-math-routines---libamath)

In their example they compile programs in this way:

```
gcc code_with_math_routines.c -lamath -lm
```

But when I try g++ as follow:

```
g++ code_with_math_routines.cpp -lamath -lm
```

This will give an undefined reference error and the math function are not recognized.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the difference between gcc and g++ command?

Comment: The options are the same. Which exact function is not tecognized?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I am using the Arm SVE version of expf(), to be specific, svfloat32_t _ZGVsMxv_expf(svfloat32_t, svbool_t). I can compile with gcc, but does not work for g++

Comment: Show the code. Createa an [MCVE]. `be specific, svfloat32_t _ZGVsMxv_expf` did you forgot to `extern "C"`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, extern "C" solves the problem. I am new to cpp, thank you very much!